# Current URL to variable and variable to regular exp

Tags: php, regex, url, seo

sorry for bad english...
I need a code for SEO clean the circuit URLs, need regexp that get current URL and swap all **< a**, **href** and **a>** to **< i**, **title** and **i>** (that for searchengines - they will not see links and not flow page rank on it) in links that coincide with current URL, then my jQuery code swap in browser all  back to a href for links to work exemple:

current URL - http: //exemple.com/pizza/ (sorry for space )

Thу сode:

```
<div>
    <a title="Some text" href="http://exemple.com/pizza/">Pizza</a><br>
    <a title="Text 2" href="http://exemple.com/salads/">Salad</a>
</div>
```

I need that code will looks like:

```
 <div>
        <i class="asd" title="http://exemple.com/pizza/">Pizza</i><br>
        <a class="asd" href="http://exemple.com/salads/">Salad</a>
    </div>
```

When i'm on a http:// exemple.com/pizza/ page, and

```
 <div>
        <a class="asd" href="http://exemple.com/pizza/">Pizza</a><br>
        <i class="asd" title="http://exemple.com/salads/">Salad</i>
    </div>
```

...when on http:// exemple.com/salads/

Now trying that:

```
$current='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
return (preg_replace('/<a(.*)href="('.$current.')"(.*)<\/a/','<i$1title="$2"$3<\/i>',$buffer));
echo $buffer;
```

But $current in pattern not works.. when i try to put http://exemple.com/pizza/ - it works, but i need a code, that will work on every page and swap the **a** tags of urls that coincide with current page url... plz help

Comment: Useless echo after return

Comment: What is inside $buffer?

Comment: ob_start("callback"); - at the top of page, to get page content
and function callback($buffer) {
//here the return preg_repl... with $buffer
ob_end_flush();
} - to swap in page content..

Comment: does enyone know how to do that??